# javascript, strange comparison operator

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

I've met "**!==**" strange comparison operator in source code of some chrome extension. Code snippet:

```
function closedTab(id) {
   if (openedTabs[id] !== undefined) {
      openedTabs[id].time = timeNow(0);
      closedTabs.unshift(openedTabs[id]);
   }
}
```

This operator is not used just once, so there's should some meaning.

Is "**!==**" came from some JavaScript magic? Or it's just equivalent to usual "!="?
Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `!==` doesn't try to convert its operands to the same type before comparing. Same with `===` and `==`.

See this question: [Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

!== is the not identity comparison operator.

!= will coerce the two types to match

!== will not coerce the two types

For a few examples:

```
3 == "3"    // true - the operands are coerced to the same type, then compared and they match
3 === "3"   // false - the operands are not coerced to the same type, so do not match
3 != "3"    // false
3 !== "3"   // true
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called a strict comparison operator where it not only checks for value but also for type.

Answer (score 2):

The difference comes from what happens when values are of different type.

The `!==` operator (and its cousin `===`) checks on the equality of both value and type. `!=` and `==` on the other hand try to coerce values to be the same before checking equality.

For example:

```
if(5 === "5")      // evaluates to false
if(5 == "5")       // evaluates to true
```

The same concept is extended to `!=` and `!==`

Answer (score 2):

It's an identical comparison operator. It compares value and type. For example:

```
if('foobar' == true) // true
if('foobar' === true) // false
```